# Chain of expression in Velocity

Tags: velocity

I have a input like `abcd/1234/rftg/74574/werf` , I want to convert into output `abcd_rftg_werf` . I want numeric part to be removed and replaced with `_`
.Can some one please help

I am trying to execute below code but its not working

```
#foreach ($element in $input.split("/"))
    #if($element.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"))
        $element
    #end
#end
```